# Why doesn't the Event Loop retrieve from the Callback Queue when the Call Stack is empty?

Tags: javascript, callstack, event-loop

I am aware that the Event Loop takes the first callback from the Callback Queue when the Call Stack is empty.

With this premise, why does the below code execute `sync2()` before the `setTimeout`s' callbacks waiting in the Callback Queue?

```js
const baseData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 100];

function asyncRun(arr, fn) {
  arr.forEach((v, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => fn(i), 0);
  });
};

function sync1() {
  baseData.forEach((v, i) => {
    console.log("sync1 -", i);
  });
}

function sync2() {
  baseData.forEach((v, i) => {
    console.log("sync2 -", i);
  });
}

asyncRun(baseData, (idx) => console.log("async -", idx));
sync1();
for (let i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++) {} // approx. 5 seconds to make sure `setTimeout`s' callbacks are ready to be pushed to the call stack.
// At this point, the Call stack is empty and there are callbacks waiting in the Callback Queue.
sync2();
```

**Output**

```
sync1 - 0
sync1 - 1
sync1 - 2
sync2 - 0
sync2 - 1
sync2 - 2
async - 0
async - 1
async - 3
```

**What I Expected**

```
sync1 - 0
sync1 - 1
sync1 - 2
async - 0
async - 1
async - 3
sync2 - 0
sync2 - 1
sync2 - 2
```

Comment: "*`// At this point, the Call stack is empty and there are callbacks waiting in the Callback Queue.`*" - well no, it's not empty. The script evaluation is still continuing.

Comment: Notice that the loop doesn't put anything onto the call stack either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is correct, but in the moment when long loop is done you have a **global** execution context on the stack. So the program will be executed until the last line and then the callstack will be empty as the global context will leave. In that moment the event loop will check the task queue.

In other words all your sync code will be executed (in your case sync1, long loop and sync2) before the event loop starts to execute async code.